# Printing results without html elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Using Beautifulsoup4 I am parsing the news website. But I can not handle to get rid of the html elements to get pure text.

There is also one problem that the published date of the news is not in date format, I would like to change it to date format so i can filter the unnecessary news out.

I am wondering which format would be useful for me to store the data? I will use it in ML to train model.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

URL = 'http://marja.az/search?q='

# if there is a prabel inside of keyword merge with + sign
KEYWORDS = ['Valizada',
            ]

for key in KEYWORDS:
    search_url = URL + key
    print(search_url)
    r = requests.get(search_url)
    soup = bs(r.content, "lxml")
    for data in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "searchNews"}):
        for a in data.find_all("a"):
            href = a.get("href")
            # print(href)
            link = "http://marja.az/" + href
            print(link)
            r1 = requests.get(link)
            soup1 = bs(r1.content, "lxml")
            header = soup1.findAll("h1", attrs={"class": "title"})
            print(header)
            paragraph = soup1.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "text"})
            for p in paragraph:
                print(p.findAll('p', text=True, recursive=False))
            date = soup1.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "left"})
            for d in date:
                print(soup1.find('div', {'style': 'color: #af0000; margin:10px 0px 10px 0px; font-size:12px; '
                                                  'font-weight:bold; text-align:left;'}))
```

Desired Result:

```
Date, Header, Content
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
soup1 = bs(r1.content, "lxml")
# header
header = soup1.find("h1", attrs={"class": "title"}).text
print(header)

# content
content = []
paragraph = soup1.find("div", attrs={"class": "text"}).findAll('p', text=True, recursive=False)
for p in paragraph:
    content.append(p.text)
    content_text = "".join(content)
    print(content_text)

# date
date = soup1.find('div', {'style': 'color: #af0000; margin:10px 0px 10px 0px; font-size:12px; ''font-weight:bold; text-align:left;'}).text

date = date.split(",")[0].split(" ")
date = date[0] + "." + date[1] + "." + date[2]
print(date)
```

Comment: Can we make `date` variable with date format? and also there is lots of blank spaces between lines, can we make it disappear?

Comment: @ValiValizada, please check an edited answer, and accept the answer if it's useful

Comment: Content is printing same thing cumulative when joinin bu i need the last one.